# Как извлечь данные из array?

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте, есть такой array полученный через parse_str ( `88978knf4ae6c3715869b1a6d59ff7a35c60cshe15s84g4dd43cea3c48484848606bd6646e46db25&expires_in=0&user_id=101115877&email=wow@doge.pet`):

```
Array ( [88978knf4ae6c3715869b1a6d59ff7a35c60cshe15s84g4dd43cea3c48484848606bd6646e46db25] => [expires_in] => 0 [user_id] => 101115877 [email] => wow@doge.pet )
```

Как можно оттуда вытащить `88978knf4ae6c3715869b1a6d59ff7a35c60cshe15s84g4dd43cea3c48484848606bd6646e46db25`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что Вы хотите получить это ключ массива.
Все ключи можно получить с помощью `array_keys`
Так как нужно получить первый ключ:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$key = $keys[0];
```

Или:

```
reset($arr); // Сброс курсора, возможно необязательно :)
$key = key($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовать array_key, при условии, конечно-же, что этот хэш у вас всегда идет первым.

```
parse_str("88978knf4ae6c3715869b1a6d59ff7a35c60cshe15s84g4dd43cea3c48484848606bd6646e46db25&expires_in=0&user_id=101115877&email=wow@doge.pet", $ar);
    $ak = array_keys($ar);
    echo $ak[0];
```

Так-же можно перебирать все ключи и отметать все имеющие осмысленное имя и значение - email, user_id и прочие.

Comment: Да, всегда первый